# What solid elements, if formed into their thinnest possible 'sheet', would be translucent?

Tags: material-science

Would this have to be experimentally done or is there some manner to estimate translucency based on molecular properties?

Answer (score 3):

Every solid object, deposited in a smooth film a single monolayer thick on a transparent substrate, transmits some/most visible light (even metal, graphene and other carbon allotropes, and resonant molecules).  In fact it’s more difficult to think of a material/color combination for which most of the light is absorbed.  The interaction length is just too small on a single nanometer length scale to absorb or reflect a majority of the light.

And yes, transparency can be estimated purely theoretically. Computational physicists might use density functional theory, for example, to estimate the electrical properties of a proposed material.  Then some basic quantum mechanics can calculate the absorption bands etc.  Finally, it’s easy classical electrodynamics to compute the transmittance for a given thickness of material.

Comment: Is there a list of the transparency of elements because a statement like 'copper is more transparent than aluminum' might be correct but without context would be absurd to a layman.

Comment: @RandyZeitman “Copper is more transparent than aluminum” without context would be absurd to a professional as well. If you’re comparing those metals, what really matters is their thicknesses and what materials surround them. According to their conductivities in the visible range, copper has less absorption for the same thickness. But for thin films, coherent interference still matters, and you need to crunch the numbers to see how the comparison turns out.

Comment: Let me add that for the calculation of such optical properties it may be a good idea to go beyond DFT and use the GW approximation to many-body perturbation theory. This will nearly directly give you the dielectric function of the material and also bandstructures that are much more accurate than those from DFT calculations. I think the dielectric function is the natural starting point to calculate for which frequencies and to which extent a material is translucent.

Comment: @GregorMichalicek Thank you for your input! Being an experimentalist myself, I appreciate the detail you can provide.

Comment: for visible light at least, the difference in the transparency of copper of any thickness vs. the transparency of aluminum at the same thickness is immaterial in pretty much any application I can think of. Does that help?